# Access objects separately in a nested array

Tags: ruby, variable-assignment

How can I access the three objects in this hash separately?

```
hash = {"Paul" => [25, 18]}
```

In this code,

```
hash.each_pair do |k, v|
  print "#{k}: "
  v.each do |n|
    print "#{n} "
  end
  print "\n"
end
```

the variable `n` accesses `[25, 18]` as a single object. Doing for example `|n, m|` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could something like below

```
hash = {}
hash["Paul"] = [25, 18]

hash.each_pair do |k, (v1, v2, *rest)|
    print "#{k}: "
    print "#{v1} "
    print "#{v2} "
    print "\n"
end
#=> Paul: 25 18
```

Alternatively, you could try something like below:

```
hash = {}
hash["Paul"] = [25, 18]

hash.each_pair do |k, v|
    print "#{k}: "
    v.tap { |m, n| 
        print "#{m} "
        print "#{n} "
    }
    print "\n"
end
#=> Paul: 25 18
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p [hash.keys, hash.values].flatten
  # ["Paul", 25, 18]
```